# MatLab Radio buttons functions

Tags: matlab, radio-button

I have two radio buttons which are connected to the text path, so i am trying to get the text paths cleared up when I hit either of the radio button. This is my code so for:

```
%initialise the radio button
set(handles.nefFile,'Value',1)
set(handles.tiffFile,'Value',0)

% --- Executes on radio button press in .NEF.
function nefFile_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    if get(handles.hObject,'Value')
        set(handles.file1Path,'',text)
        set(handles.file2Path,'',text)
    else
        set(handles.file1Path,'String',text)
        set(handles.file2Path,'String',text)
    end
guidata(hObject,handles);

% --- Executes on radio button press in .TIFF.
function tiffFile_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

end
```

Comment: And you question is....??

Comment: my question is when i click on either ofthe radio button the text paths dont get cleared

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
set(handles.file1Path,'',text)
set(handles.file2Path,'',text)
```

with

```
set(handles.file1Path,'String','')
set(handles.file2Path,'String','')
```

Comment: what is 'String' doing there?